# Enable 32 bits compilation on Debian squeeze (6) 64 with backports (after deprecation)

Tags: debian, dpkg

I try to compile softwares with a 32 bits `libc`, old enough to be compatible with my customers.

So I have installed **Debian Squeeze (6) 64 bits** this last days (so after deprecation date) in a ProXmox container.

I have set the archive repositories to allow me to update / install packages, it works. My `sources.list` is:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
# Backports
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
# Security
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

I have to say, there was a lot of outdated GPG Keys, and after update, a few are always outdated, they seem to be unsupported anymore.

My current version of `dpkg` is 1.15.11 the original Squeeze versio where the `multiarch` functionnality is not present. It apears only in 1.16... 
Good enough, the backports listed upper contain wheezy packages where dpkg is in version 1.16.9 .

http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-backports/pool/main/d/dpkg/

But I am not able to install this backports. When I run the command

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports dpkg
```

It responds:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dpkg is already the newest version.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`apt-get policy dpkg` returns

```
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.15.11
  Candidate: 1.15.11
  Version table:
 *** 1.15.11 0
        500 http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If I ask, it's because I am pretty sure to have set things right. I guess I am on the frontier where archived versions have there limits.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt-cache policy dpkg`?

Comment: Also, since you’re installing a VM seemingly for the sole purpose of building software with an old 32-bit C library, why not install 32-bit Debian 6 directly? Then you wouldn’t have to involve cross-architecture builds.

Comment: @Stephen sure... but I don't really know what this info means.
 I haven't found a prepared container base in 32 bits... and I have other compilation environements where the 64bits are not a problem, I assumed it would be the same with this dist.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` after adding backports to `sources.list`?

Comment: You might not actually need multi-arch at all; try installing `gcc-multilib` and building with `gcc -m32`.

Comment: @Stephen: If I run `apt-get update` first: yes. - 
With `gcc-multilib` it compiles !!! Thx - 
I found some old container templates here: https://openvz.org/Download/template/precreated

Comment: OK, the `dpkg` thing is weird but I’ve added the multilib approach as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 32-bit (`i386`) build on a 64-bit (`amd64`) on Debian 6, you shouldn’t need multi-arch; if you install `gcc-multilib` or `g++-multilib` (depending on your goal) and compile with `gcc -m32` (or `g++ -m32`) you should get the result you’re after.